# random dice nr, javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make these three functions at the top into one and still not get the same random nr at each dice, when i click a button to roll all three? to clearify the functions are for when i click on a single dice, and the function at the bottom is for when i want to roll all three att the same time! all of it works my question is only if it could be done with less code?

```
function rollDice1(){
    var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;  
    dice1.src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
}

function rollDice2(){
    var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;  
    dice2.src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
}

function rollDice3(){
    var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;
    dice3.src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
}

function rollDices() {
    rollDice1();
    rollDice2();
    rollDice3();    
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize  `dice1`, `dice2` and `dice3` ?

Comment: *and still not get the same random nr at each dice* - your code does not guarantee that dices are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a parameter to the function so when called you can pass in the die to be set.  This assumes `dice1`, `dice2` and `dice3` are global variables.

```
function rollDice(di){
    var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;  
    di.src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
}

function rollDices() {
    rollDice(dice1);
    rollDice(dice2);
    rollDice(dice3);    
}
```

Comment: then it says cannot set roperty of src to undefined

Comment: All three calls should be to rollDice() now, not rollDice1() etc.

Comment: but only when i click on one seperate dice, why is this? when i press button to roll all three it works fine?

Comment: yes that i understood, and that function works perfectly but not the seperate ones when i click only one dice it says src undefined

Comment: they are all global variables! cant understand how it can work in the rollDices function and not the onclick="rollDice(dice1)" on each picture?

Comment: @spovell Glad you figured it out I had to step out for a second

Answer (score 1):

You can loop, no need to call an external function thrice :

```
function rollDices() {
    for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
       var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;
       window['dice'+i].src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
    } 
}
```

It could be better by having an array instead of three separate variables for `dice1`, `dice2` and `dice3` (I supposed here that they were global variables).

Answer (score 0):

I would actually prefer to go with an [OO-approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming); simply created different Dice-objects that can be rolled.

```
function Dice() {

    var self = this;

    this.face;

    this.roll = function () {
        var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;
        self.face = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
        return randomDice;
    };

};

var dice1 = new Dice(),
    dice2 = new Dice(),
    dice3 = new Dice();

dice1.roll();
dice2.roll();
dice3.roll();

console.log(dice1.face);
console.log(dice2.face);
console.log(dice3.face);
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PXErm/).

(Take note it's incomplete; when the Dice hasn't been rolled, the face is `undefined`. You might want to take steps in order to prevent that state).

Comment: The problem with OOP approach applied to simple things is that it make simple problems verbose and less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is:

```
function rollDice(times){
    var randomDices = [];
    while (randomDices.length < times)  {
        var rand = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;
        if(randomDices.indexOf(rand) > -1 == false)
            randomDices.push(rand);
    }
    return randomDices
}
```

The above code returns an array, with length you specify, of random dices.
for example `rollDice(3)` will return three random dices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variation on the accepted answer :

```
function rollDice(di) {
    var randomDice = Math.floor(6*Math.random())+1;  
    di.src = "dice/" + randomDice + ".jpg";
}

function rollDices(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        rollDice(arr[i]);
    }    
}
```

An advantage of this implementation, is that you can use any number of dice and pass along the image variables to `rollDices` in an array.

To roll one dice, you could do this :

```
rollDice(dice1);
```

However, you could also do this :

```
rollDices([dice1]);
```

To roll two dices, you could do this :

```
rollDices([dice1, dice2]);
```

To roll three dices, you could do this :

```
rollDices([dice1, dice2, dice3]);
```

To roll four dices, you could do this :

```
rollDices([dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4]);
```

Etc...